# scraping using PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser

Tags: php, html, dom, web-scraping, html-parsing

I want to use PHP simple HTML DOM parser to scrape from a website.
Source code is so random like that :

```
      <font face="Arial" color="#ff0000">
      <p>Parameters</p>
      </font><font face="Arial" size="2" color="#ff0000">
      <p>Param1</p>
      </font><font face="Arial" size="2" color="#0000ff">
      <p>Details. (Lob., </font><i><font face="Arial"
      size="2" color="#ff0000">Co v</font><font face="Arial" size="2"
      color="#0000ff">.)</p>
```

Instead of putting directly  "Details. (Lob., Co v.)" inside < p> < /p> , it's put using < font> and < i>.
When I use this code

```
foreach($html->find('p') as $p) 
{
  echo $p->plaintext.'<br>';
}
```

I find "Details. (Lob.," it stops when finding < i > or < font >.
How can I extract the whole line "Details. (Lob., Co v.)"

Thank you for your answer

Comment: Do you mean _"scrape"_? Just making sure.

Comment: Yes sorry, I mean scrape

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **strip_tags()** function to remove the unnecessary tags. after removing unnecessary tags, you can use DOM parser.

> The strip_tags() function strips a string from HTML, XML, and PHP
>   tags.
>
> string strip_tags ( string $str [, string $allowable_tags ] )

You can read more about strip_tags() function on [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php)

**Example:**

```
$html = '<font face="Arial" color="#ff0000">
    <p>Parameters</p>
    </font><font face="Arial" size="2" color="#ff0000">
    <p>Param1</p>
    </font><font face="Arial" size="2" color="#0000ff">
    <p>Details. (Lob., </font><i><font face="Arial"
    size="2" color="#ff0000">Co v</font><font face="Arial" size="2"
    color="#0000ff">.)</p>';

$html = strip_tags($string, '<p>');
echo $html;
```

**Result:**

```
  <p>Parameters</p>

  <p>Param1</p>

  <p>Details. (Lob., Co v.)</p>
```